# how to build dialog window based on class definition? (like django's model system)

Tags: c++, django, model-view-controller, visual-c++

[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/overview/) comes with this great approach, where all you have todo is write your data model, and Django will generate the correct (most basic) view according to your model properties.

E.g:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Any forms displayed by Django will already use the correct and appropriate field type that matches the property type (DateTimeField, CharField, TextField, etc).

I was wondering whether the **same is possible with `C++`**? I'm thinking of writing an application settings class, and I don't want to build the dialog window by hand. I'd prefer if I could build a dialog automatically. I don't care about the order and position of the individual input-fields. I think that this should be possible, given that I follow the Model View Controller pattern anyway.

**EDIT** I'd appreciate it if answers could include example code or links to examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ there is no reflection mechanism allowing you to query members of a class, so it is not possible to achieve what you want as easily as in Python. But, you can apply techniques used by C++ serialization libraries, for example Boost. In essence, you need to add to your class an equivalent of the boost serialization `serialize` method, which will compensate for the lack of the reflection facilities needed to retrieve information on class' members, here is a boost serialization tutorial explaining this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html.

Another option, also used by some C++ serialization systems, is to parse the C++ class source code and generate C++ code which does the serialization (in your case that would be generating GUI dialogs as well).

Comment: can you point me to an example? Wouldn't it be possible to inspect the C++ class before compiling the application and build the dialog based on that?

Comment: Study this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html Regarding 'inspecting C++ class before compiling', yes, some serialization libraries use preprocessors which parse C++ code and generate C++ code doing the serialization.